# Transparent ImageButtons get tinted when over active VideoView

Tags: android, android-imageview, imagebutton, android-videoview

When placing semi-transparent .png files (say, white rectangles with an 80% opacity) as ImageButtons over an ImageView, the buttons appear completely as expected, however if these buttons are displayed over a VideoView that is playing a video, the buttons get tinted significantly darker than they do when over the ImageView.

Interestingly enough, when I try to take a screenshot, the buttons appear normally in the screenshot! So... I cannot include pictures. This does not occur on all phones. It does occur on the Nexus 4 I am currently testing with.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: never solved it :( My project is now in a completely different state, so the problem isn't there anymore, but I have no idea how or when the issue resolved itself. I may look into it at some point, but too much else to do.

Comment: Yea i was unable to do that as well. Moved to TextureView instead of VideoView. This seem to solve the issue